# How to dynamically change icons on jsp page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, jsp

I have a jsp page where I display files saved in a folder. File names are stored in a database which I just fetch and display to the web-page. Now I want each file to have an icon based on its extension which is why I downloaded icons for all different file-types but my code doesn't seem to work.

I'm getting these errors in my browser's console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: fileIcon is not defined at HTMLImageElement.onload
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token 
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

**folder.jsp** *(This is the webpage where icons, filename, created date, and actions are displayed)*

```
<table class="list-view">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>File</th>
        <th>Created Date</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach var="j" items="${files}">
        <tr>
            <td><img src="resources/images/icons/file.svg" class="file-icon" id="file-icon" onload="fileIcon(${j.getFile()})"></td>
            <td id="filename">${j.getFile()}</td>
            <td>${j.getCreateddate()}</td>
            <td>
                <a onclick="renameFileModal(${j.getFileid()})" class="rename"><img src="resources/images/icons/rename.svg" class="rename-icon"></a>
                <a onclick="deleteFileModal(${j.getFileid()})" class="delete"><img src="resources/images/icons/delete-file.svg" class="delete-icon"></a>
                <a href="" class="download" download="${j.getFilename()}"><img src="resources/images/icons/download.svg" class="download-icon"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>           
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

**main.js**

```
function fileIcon(filename) {
    var extension = filename.substring(filename.indexOf("."), filename.length);

    if (extension == ".txt") {
        document.getElementById("file-icon").setAttribute("src", "resources/images/icons/txt.svg");
    }

    if (extension == ".pdf") {
        document.getElementById("file-icon").setAttribute("src", "resources/images/icons/pdf.svg");
    }

    if (extension == ".jpeg") {
        document.getElementById("file-icon").setAttribute("src", "resources/images/icons/jpeg.svg");
    }

    if (extension == ".jpg") {
        document.getElementById("file-icon").setAttribute("src", "resources/images/icons/jpg.svg");
    }

    if (extension == ".png") {
        document.getElementById("file-icon").setAttribute("src", "resources/images/icons/png.svg");
    }

    if (extension == ".gif") {
        document.getElementById("file-icon").setAttribute("src", "resources/images/icons/gif.svg");
    }
}
```

I put these `if` statements to check if this is giving me the desired result because these files are present in the folder, and it isn't working. What changes should I do in order to change the icons? If there is another approach that I can use, let me know and I will try that out as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Instead of going for JavaScript, I defined `extension` and `icon` variables in my POJO class `Files`

In my DAO class,`FileSharingDao`, I defined two methods `public String extractExtension(String filename)` and `public String getIcon(String extension)`. The former method enabled me to get the extension from the filename while the latter worked like this:

```
public String getIcon(String extension) {
        String icon;

        System.out.println(extension);

        switch (extension) {
                // cases go here
                case ".css":
                    icon = "css.svg";
                    break;
        }
        return icon;
}
```

This function is called from `getFiles()` method which is in my DAO class.

```
public ArrayList<Files> getFiles(int folderid, int userid) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ArrayList<Files> fileList = new ArrayList<Files>();

    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = DatabaseConnection.getDatabase().getConnection()
            .prepareStatement(GET_FILES_QUERY);
    preparedStatement.setInt(1, folderid);
    preparedStatement.setInt(2, userid);
    ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

    while (resultSet.next()) {
        Files file = new Files();
        file.setFileid(resultSet.getInt("id"));
        file.setFolderid(resultSet.getInt("folderid"));
        file.setFilename(resultSet.getString("filename"));
        file.setCreateddate(convertDate(resultSet.getString("createddate")));
        file.setFile(resultSet.getString("file"));
        file.setLastmodified(convertDate(resultSet.getString("lastmodified")));
        file.setExtension(extractExtension(resultSet.getString("file")));
        file.setIcon(getIcon(extractExtension(resultSet.getString("file"))));
        file.setUserid(userid);

        fileList.add(file);
    }

    close(preparedStatement, resultSet);

    return fileList;
}
```

From my controller, I call `getFiles()` using this method:

```
@RequestMapping("/folder")
public ModelAndView folder(HttpServletRequest request) {
    int folderid = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("folderid"));
    int userid = (Integer) request.getSession().getAttribute("userid");
    request.getSession().setAttribute("folderid", folderid);

    ArrayList<Files> files;

    FileSharingDao fileShare = new FileSharingDao();
    try {
        files = fileShare.getFiles(folderid, userid);
        request.setAttribute("files", files);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new ModelAndView("folder");
}
```

I then access `files` on my jsp page like this:

```
<c:forEach var="j" items="${files}">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="resources/images/icons/${j.getIcon()}" class="file-icon" id="file-icon">
        </td>
        <td>${j.getFile()}</td>
        <td>${j.getLastmodified()}</td>
        <td>
            <a onclick="renameFileModal(${j.getFileid()})" class="rename">
                <img src="resources/images/icons/rename.svg" class="rename-icon">
            </a>

            <a onclick="deleteFileModal(${j.getFileid()})" class="delete">
                <img src="resources/images/icons/delete.svg" class="delete-icon">
            </a>

            <a href="" class="download" download="${j.getFilename()}"> 
                <img src="resources/images/icons/download.svg" class="download-icon">
                </a>
                <a>
                    <img src="resources/images/icons/share.svg" class="share-icon">
                </a>
        </td>
    </tr>           
</c:forEach>
```

And this did it. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

From the code base i can not see anything bad. That should usually work. S i think there is something wrong with the program flow or when things are loaded.
there are a few things which do the same but different.

- You could set the images by a stylesheet rule.
- you could preload the images into window vars (old school) Then the are definitly there
- you could set the image source by javascript.

  somehow this editor does not like it so well. Just encode the image base64 and embed them directly. Same trick will work also in a css style which is a better idea. in this case you just has to add a style rule and a class to the element later on.

sorry this i can not get in the code tag:
var
filesvg="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdC    b3g9IjAgMCAzMjAgNTEyIj48cGF0aCBkPSJNMzAyLjE4OSAzMjkuMTI2SDE5Ni4xMDVsNTUuODMxIDEzNS45OTNjMy44ODkgOS40MjgtLjU1NSAxOS45OTktOS40NDQgMjMuOTk5bC00OS4xNjUgMjEuNDI3Yy05LjE2NSA0LTE5LjQ0My0uNTcxLTIzLjMzMi05LjcxNGwtNTMuMDUzLTEyOS4xMzYtODYuNjY0IDg5LjEzOEMxOC43MjkgNDcyLjcxIDAgNDYzLjU1NCAwIDQ0Ny45NzdWMTguMjk5QzAgMS44OTkgMTkuOTIxLTYuMDk2IDMwLjI3NyA1LjQ0M2wyODQuNDEyIDI5Mi41NDJjMTEuNDcyIDExLjE3OSAzLjAwNyAzMS4xNDEtMTIuNSAzMS4xNDF6Ii8+PC9zdmc+"

this can now be added to the attribute.

image by csv

```
<style>
.svgimg { 
width:100%; height:150px; 
background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' 
viewBox='0 0 100 44' height='44' width='100'><path d='m 0,11 100,0' 
style='stroke:#efefef;stroke-width:21.5px' /></svg>")
}
</style>
```

to be set as a background to a div for example. (Looks same). Also by this the base 64 trick shown above will work. If the css is loaded also your images are loaded. I use the csv thing for such issues. It is also damn fast :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I achieved the dynamic icon change by porting the `function fileIcon(filename)` to my Spring controller class. I set the icons in an ArrayList based on their appearance position and set the ArrayList in the session object which I then directly use in the jsp page.

Comment: :) That is for sure one of the the "de luxe" versions.  But it might be a bit more as you can await from this page ;) I have put my icons into a sql database. I stupidly have "some" of them (As well as acc. functions, Hints, Help pages and so on). This is also not a "everybody can use version". But also "de luxe" :)